# Converting a 2d array (grayscale image) into 3d (rgb image) array

Tags: numpy

I have a grayscale image as 2d numpy array. I wanted to convert it into RGB image as 3d numpy array.

The RGB color was produced randomly.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(25, 25))
uniq_data = np.unique(data)
print (uniq_data)

colors = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(len(uniq_data), 3))

result = ?
```

I could not figure out how to do it.

I need to put unique color (RGB value) for unique data.
The output shape would be (25, 25, 3).

Comment: `np.random.randint(...,size=(25,25,3))`

Comment: @MarkSetchell It would be expected shape of the result. However, how to convert real `data` into this shape by assigning unique color (RGB value) for unique data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a lookup table and use it by means of advanced indexing:

```
lookup = np.zeros((255,3),dtype=np.uint8)
lookup[uniq_data] = colors
rgb = lookup[data]
```

Comment: It worked but could not understood how? What is `255`?

Comment: @Col I don't understand. What do you mean "What is 255?" ? Anyway, perhaps start by reading https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: I mean, why `np.zeros((255,3)`? there is `255`.

Comment: @Col Sorry, still don't get you. 3 for rgb, 255 for 255 gray levels. Did you mean to create 256? You have to put high=256 then.